# Paperback from the 80s where a fight against aliens attacking Earth begins with an F15 intercepting them over Colorado

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I read a paperback in the early 80s, can't remember the title. Aliens were going to attack Earth but Earth was warned as scouts attacked early around Colorado and we figured them out. The planet got together and built a huge grazer (LASER except for Gamma rays, not light) to destroy the incoming fleet.  The book starts with an F15 pilot intercepting over Colorado.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art, or the names of any characters?

Comment: Possibly this one: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159792/book-about-an-attempted-alien-invasion
 which is a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110477/looking-for-sci-fi-book-about-alien-invasion-where-earth-builds-a-giant-laser-to

Comment: Book available on the Internet Archive at https://archive.org/details/invaderhill00hill/ and indeed they first encounter the scout UFOs in an F-15 flying over Colorado Springs.

Comment: @nebogipfel An answer is worth posting as such.

Answer (score 9):

As shown in the comments, the answer is [Invader](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3274511-invader) by Albert Fay Hill and David Campbell Hill. The F-15 meeting scouts over Colorado Springs, and the 'graser' weapon, are both in the book. The answer is a duplicate as stated above.

Comment: Note that the spelling of the weapon, as befits its derivation from "laser" is "graser" with an "s."

Comment: Yeah, but we say it with a pronounced Z

Comment: They destroyed the incoming fleet with a huge herbivore?

Comment: Mmmm, spaceships! Nom-nom-nom...